# Django ElasticBeanstalk change bucket

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been using the service of amazon ElasticBeanstalk and it seems that it creates automatically a bucket for the Django application in order to save the static files. I want to upload my second django application in this service, however I am worried about using the same bucket with two different application. 
I took a look on the .ebextesions/name_app.config in order to assign a new bucket, but I could not find anything.

I have two questions here.

Does the new django application interfere with the other application by using the same bucket?

Is it possible to use a new bucket with ElasticBeanstalk?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. ElasticBeanstalk creates a S3 bucket named `elasticbeanstalk-region-account-id`
   for each region you create environment.

Your new django application will not interfere with the other in the same bucket, as it create two different folder of your django environment which has their respective runtime folder having current version files residing here:

```
bucketName/resources/environments/environmentID/_runtime/_versions
```

2. You cannot create new bucket for elasticBeanstalk application, you can delete it by changing its bucket policy.

Hope this helps you!